# Respak database connection with PHP

Tags: php

How to connect with Respak database from PHP. I need to insert a user in respak database if it is not already existing there..

Is there any documentation available for this ? I didnt find anything in internet.

Comment: your best bet would be contacting the vendor then

Comment: What is `Respak Database` ?? Even Google seem to be lost https://www.google.com/search?q=Respak+database&oq=Respak+database&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: ResPAK is a Restaurant Management Module for online restaurant reservations. I need to integrate this with PHP for one of my client. Searched in internet a lot, but didnt get any useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is not a complex thing. Two methods are available for this.

You can connect to the ResPAK with a firebird database in the following 2 ways

1) Connect to Respak using firebird from PHP itself.

2) If you have any problem connecting firebird in PHP, then you can use .Net for connecting firebird and Respak. It is more easy. Write required functions in .net interface and call them as webservices from PHP. I am using this way for my project.

Thanks,

Harry,

http://www.innovativewebz.com